# Please help me understand this linear algebra proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation, schur-decomposition

Please help me understand the proof below.

Here are my questions:

1.) what does **r**$_1$ represent?

2.) is $A_1$ just matrix $A$ with the first row and first column deleted?

3.) what does $\tilde{r_1}$ represent?

4.) why does **r**$_1$$Y$=[**r**$_{12}$$\tilde{r_1}$]

I'm sorry if this is a difficult question to answer. I can't tell if I am confused by some notational stuff or if I am not understanding some concepts. Please help me arrive at an understanding of this proof.

[image]

Comment: Do not post unsearchable images of text and equations.  Instead, typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: Is this a rule? I wasn't aware of it. I am new to MathJax. It would probably take me well over an hour to replicate this image without mistakes. I think the image is as clear anything typeset using MathJax. What would typing this entire thing out do to benefit  you, me, or anyone else?

Comment: @JackK95 It's not an official rule, but it is discouraged. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/225147) for a detailed explanation

Comment: @JackK95:  The reason to typeset is so that the internal search engine on the site can find the text and equations.  Suppose someone else tries to post the *EXACT SAME QUESTION*.  While they're typing it, the site *should* alert them to the fact that the question has already been asked (and likely answered).  But your posting *prevents* this, as there is no way for the search engine to read the image.  Clear now?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Do not issue commands to users making a sincere effort to use the site. Instead, engage in polite discourse, especially with those who are still getting their bearings

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this question, Ben.

Comment: OK:  @JackK95... now that the reasons for typesetting have been explained, and your explicit question answered, *please* go back and fix your question.  Thank you very much for making this site better.  I trust Ben Grossman supports this good-faith request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1,2: in the equations
$$
\begin{align}
AX &= \cdots = \pmatrix{\lambda \mathbf x_1 & A \mathbf x_2 & \cdots & A \mathbf x_n}
\\ & = \pmatrix{\mathbf x_1 & \mathbf x_2 & \cdots & \mathbf  x_n} \pmatrix{\lambda_1 & \mathbf r_1 \\ 0 & A_1} = \cdots,
\end{align}
$$
the point being made is that there exists *some* matrix $M$ for which $AX = [\mathbf x_1 \  \ \cdots \ \  \mathbf x_n] M$, and this $M$ must have the first column $[\lambda_1,0,\dots,0].$ An efficient way to convey this is to avoid introducing the matrix $M$ and instead use the block-partitioned matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 & \mathbf r_1 \\ 0 & A_1}.
$$
So, to answer your question, $\mathbf r_1$ is a $1 \times (n-1)$ row-vector and $A_1$ is an $(n - 1) \times (n-1)$ matrix. Both of these are submatrices of the (unique) matrix $M$ satisfying $AX = XM$.

Regarding 3,4, we have the same thing going on. The author would like to break up the $1 \times (n-1)$ matrix $\mathbf r_1 Y$ into two submatrices. $r_{12}$ is the first entry of $\mathbf r_1 Y$, and $\tilde {\mathbf r}_1$ is the $1 \times (n-2)$ matrix built from the remaining entries of $\mathbf r_1 Y$.

Comment: I am having trouble grasping what the contents of the row vector r might look like? Can I say or conclude anything about what its contents might be? Sorry if this quesiton is really vague.

Comment: @JackK95 There is no row-vector $\mathbf r$. The only things that can be guaranteed about the vectors $\mathbf r_1, \tilde {\mathbf r}_{1}, \mathbf r_2$ are the number of entries that they contain.

Comment: But what is it that makes the entries of these row vectors different than the corresponding entries of matrix A?

Comment: @JackK95 I don't understand your question. Why would you think that they are the same?

Comment: @JackK95 Of course if we start with an $A$ whose first column has the desired form $(\lambda_1,0,\dots,0)$, then we could choose $X = I$, and in this case $M = A$ and $\mathbf r_1$ is a submatrix of $A$